# Remove all but specified hashtags at the end of a string using regex

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have a regex expression that almost works as I'd like, but I need advice on how to remove all but selected hashtags only at the end of a string.

Right now I have the following:

```
preg_replace('/(?!#hashtag|#DoNotRemoveThis)(#[\w-]+)/', '', $post_caption);
```

Input **(remove bold)**:
Any #hashtag in the middle of the string should NOT be removed regardless of what it is, for example #DoNotRemoveThis  #KeepThisHashtag and any hashtag at the end of the string should be removed UNLESS it matches the exeptions in the regex. **#deletethis** #DoNotRemoveThis **#thismustgoawa**y

Wanted output:
Any #hashtag in the middle of the string should NOT be removed regardless of what it is, for example #DoNotRemoveThis  #KeepThisHashtag and any hashtag at the end of the string should be removed UNLESS it matches the exeptions in the regex. #DoNotRemoveThis

The only problem with this is that it also removes unspecified hashtags in the middle of the string – I want all hashtags inside the string to be kept intact, and all hashtags at the end (except the excluded ones) to be removed.

Please see the live example for a better understanding: https://regex101.com/r/A0Ebor/1

Comment: `/(?!#hashtag|#DoNotRemoveThis)(#[\w-]+)$/`
Try adding a dollar sign (signifies end of string) at the end of your Regex

Comment: Ok, I understand: a sequence of hashtags at the end is meant.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I want to remove #deletethis and #thismustgoaway. The other hashtags should be untouched.

Comment: Try [`#(?!(?:hashtag|DoNotRemoveThis)\b)[\w-]+(?=(?:\s+#[\w-]+)*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Se4WGL/3)

Comment: In your example, the 3rd last hashtag (#deletethis) should not be deleted, correct? Because it isn't at the end of the string... So why did you name it #deletethis?? Please clarify

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon I've added input and expected output to the original post, #deletethis and #thismustgoaway should be removed.

Comment: @Lenny: See my answer, I think it is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'/#(?!(?:hashtag|DoNotRemoveThis)\b)[\w-]+(?=(?:\s+#[\w-]+)*\s*$)/iu'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Se4WGL/7).

**Details**

- `#` - a hash symbol
- `(?!(?:hashtag|DoNotRemoveThis)\b)` - fails the match if there is a `hashtag` or `DoNotRemoveThis` followed with a word boundary
- `[\w-]+` - 1 or more word chars or hyphens
- `(?=(?:\s+#[\w-]+)*$)` - only return a match if immediately to the right of the current location, there is:

  - `(?:\s+#[\w-]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\s+` - 1+ whitespace
    - `#[\w-]+` - a hash + one or more word chars or hyphens
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (in case there are trailing whitespaces)
  - `$`  - end of string (may be proceeded with a newline, if it is not expected, replace with `\z`)

The `/i` at the end will make the pattern case insensitive.

I assume hastags end with a word char, hence, `\b`. Remove if you want to match any hashtags but those that *start with* `hashtag` or `DoNotRemoveThis`.

The `u` UNICODE modifier makes the regex work well with all Unicode letters and digits in the input strings, and also makes `\w` Unicode aware (it will match all Unicode letters, digits, and `_` char).

If we are to speak about *optimizations*, and *enchancing pattern efficiency*, in PCRE, it makes sense performing a check for `hashtag` and `DoNotRemoveThis` *after* we match the `#` followed with word/hyphen chars. However, to make it work, we need to

- split the lookaround into several ones as in a PCRE regex it is not possible to use an alternation (it makes the lookbehind length unknown and such lookbehinds are not supported)
- use an atomic group over the `#[\w-]+` pattern, ie. `(?>#[\w-]+)`, or possessive quantifier `++` (i.e. `#[\w-]++` that disables backtracking into the pattern.

So, you may use a pattern like in Casimir's answer, or an atomic group variation:

```
'/#(?>[\w-]+)(?<!#hashtag|#DoNotRemoveThis)(?=(?:\s+#[\w-]+)*\s*$)/ui'
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Se4WGL/8).

Comment: This works perfectly – one question though: where in the regex would I put  /i to make it case insensitive?

Comment: See my update, just add the `i` modifier after the trailing [**regex delimiter**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) `/`.

Comment: Ah, I mistakenly assumed it'd be a / since that was used in another example. The addition of \s*$ will come in handy as well, thanks a lot for your help Wiktor.

Comment: What is the point of the `/i` at the end if `\w` matches both uppercase and lowercase latters?

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon Because the `hashtag|DoNotRemoveThis` contains letters.

Comment: oh i see, didnt think of that :/

Comment: The regex seems to break when a special character such as å, ä and ö is in the string, what do I need to add to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Add a `u` modifier, `/iu`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, your detailed explenation is also very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
~#[\w-]++(?<!#hashtag|#DoNotRemoveThis)(?=(?:\s+#[\w-]+)*+\s*$)\s*~
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/QJkHaz/2)

details:

```
~
#[\w-]++   # match a hashtag (and forbids backtracking using a possessive quantifier)
(?<!#hashtag|#DoNotRemoveThis) # check if the tag isn't forbidden
(?=(?:\s+#[\w-]+)*+\s*$) # check if the tag is followed by eventual other tags until the end
\s* # match an eventual trailing whitespace
~
```

Comment: This is basically the same pattern is mine. You could just drop a comment below my answer. And it is less portable due to lookbehinds and possessive quantifiers in the pattern.

Comment: Not really, the main difference is that this one is efficient.

Comment: If you think that my answer is just a copy of yours, feel free to flag it.